# Is it possible to pass StartupService as a parameter in CreateHostBuilder?

Tags: c#, server, grpc

In order to create the project generic, I would like to receive the StartupService as a parameter. Is it possible?

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder<T, TClass>(string[] args, T service, TClass clas, Type type) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
{
  var SERVICE_PORT = EnvironmentVariable.Get("SERVICE_PORT", 8200);
  webBuilder.UseUrls($"https://+:{SERVICE_PORT}");
  webBuilder.UseStartup<StartupService>();
   //webBuilder.Ser
  })
  .ConfigureServices(svc => { svc.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(type, service));
});
```

I would like something similar to:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder<T>(string[] args, T service, Type type, **TClass StartupServiceFromExternalClass**)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilderextensions.usestartup?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-hosting-webhostbuilderextensions-usestartup-1(microsoft-aspnetcore-hosting-iwebhostbuilder-system-func((microsoft-aspnetcore-hosting-webhostbuildercontext-0)))) of `UseStartup` that accepts a `startupFactory`:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder<T, TStartup>(
    string[] args,
    T service,
    Type type,
    TStartup startupServiceFromExternalClass)
    where TStartup : class
{
    return Host
        .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            var SERVICE_PORT = EnvironmentVariable.Get("SERVICE_PORT", 8200);
            webBuilder.UseUrls($"https://+:{SERVICE_PORT}");
            webBuilder.UseStartup(() => startupServiceFromExternalClass);
        })
        .ConfigureServices(svc => svc.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(type, service)));
}
```